# Navigate for result in React Native without using redux

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

what is properly way to navigate for result to other screens in react native ?
I have main screen with list of items and three other screens where I can set up filters.
For the first time when I open main screen with items I see all items without filters. 
Then I want to for example set up max price, so I navigate to Price Filters Screen... but I don't know how to pass back to Main Screen the max price, when I set up it and click 'Apply'. I could pass it in params, but componentDidMount isn't run in Main Screen.

If I set up filters in Price Filters Screen and go back to Main Screen and navigate to Price Filters Screen again I want to see this filters in Price Filters Screen.

Maybe should I keep all filters in navigation params instead of in Main Screen state ?

I don't want to use redux in this case.

Comment: You can use react context api

Comment: And what about keeping this filters in navigation ?

Comment: Depends how much props drilling you need to do. It can have a negative effect on maintainability when components get props only to pass it on to children without actually needing the props.

Comment: Main Screen < - > Price Filters Screen (min price, max price, sort type),
Main Screen < - > Delivery FIlters Screen (delivery type, radius),
Main Screen < - > Category Filters Screen ( category ),

I think there aren't so much.